# how to get full path of URL including multiple parameters in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, uri

Suppose 
**URL**:   **http:/localhost:9090/project1/url.jsp?id1=one&id2=two&id3=three**

```
<%
String str=request.getRequestURL()+"?"+request.getQueryString();
System.out.println(str);
%>
```

with this i get the output 
**http:/localhost:9090/project1/url.jsp?id1=one**

but with this i am able to retrieve only 1st parameter(i.e id1=one) not other parameters

but if i use javascript i am able to retrieve all parameters

```
function a()
     {
        $('.result').html('current url is : '+window.location.href );
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

i want to retrieve current URL value to be used in my next page but i don't want to use sessions

using any of above two method how do i retrieve all parameters in jsp?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for..

```
String str=request.getRequestURL()+"?";
Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while (paramNames.hasMoreElements())
{
    String paramName = paramNames.nextElement();
    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
    for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) 
    {
        String paramValue = paramValues[i];
        str=str + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    str=str+"&";
}
System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.length()-1));    //remove the last character from String
```

Comment: everything is right except that & symbol is added at last of str printed

Comment: @lata i have updated my code, and i have tested, its working for me

Comment: It would be more correct if the last line is set to remove the last occurrence of '&' since it would then work for URLs without parameters too `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("&"))`

Answer (score 8):

Given URL = http:/localhost:9090/project1/url.jsp?id1=one&id2=two&id3=three

```
request.getQueryString();
```

Should indeed return id1=one&id2=two&id3=three

See [HttpServletRequest.getQueryString JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)

I once face the same issue, It's probably due to the some testing procedure failure.
If it happens, test in a clear environment : new browser window, etc.

Bhushan answer is not equivalent to getQueryString, as it decode parameters values !