# Get the full url of the current page in a JSPF

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, wcs

I have a url similar to this `http://localhost/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?expDataType=CatalogEntryId&catalogId=10351&urlRequestType=Base&productId=14311&expDataUniqueID=14311&errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&urlLangId=-1&langId=-1&storeId=11001`

How will I get the full url?

I have tried `request.getURL.toString()` , `request.getQueryString()` and `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")`.

but nothing gives the full path.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try request.getRequestURL().

Comment: The first one returned  `webapp/wcs/stores/Aurora/ShoppingArea/CatalogSection/CatalogEntrySubSection/ProductDisplay.jsp`

The 2nd one returned - `null`
And the 3rd one returned - `webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay`

Comment: @ Satya... yes... I tried `request.getURL().toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
 String completeURL = request.getRequestURL().toString() +"?"+ request.getQueryString();
```

or customize as per your application.

Even you can refer this : [how to get full path of URL including multiple parameters in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081061/how-to-get-full-path-of-url-including-multiple-parameters-in-jsp)

Hope it helps,
Thanks,

Comment: request.getQueryString() returns null

Comment: Than try to refer the link in answer :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081061/how-to-get-full-path-of-url-including-multiple-parameters-in-jsp

Comment: Kamal : This link helped me :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the full URL does not even comes to the application server, because the browser first open a socket to the root address, then makes an HTTP request with the rest of the it.

Consider

> http://www.mywebserver.com:12345/mypage1?param=value

The browser first open a socket to *ip address of www.mywebserver.com*:12345, then issue an HTTP GET requesto containing only *mypage1?param=value*.

That said, [HttpServelRequest.getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) under some circumstances could work. If not you should know from within your web application the address of your server, or pass it through an hidden field.